# Can someone help me with this association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying setup a Rails app that will be something like a game. The app has Users, each of which have Pawns that they can create. A User can search other users and the Pawns that they created, and challenge another one if they like, using one of their own Pawns. The challenged user can then accept/decline the challenge.

Right now I can add/delete Pawns for a User fine, and my models look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pawns, dependent: :destroy
```

and

```
class Pawn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

Now, if User1 wants to challenge a Pawn created by User2, he looks at User2's list of Pawns and clicks a "Challenge" button for the Pawn he wants. User1 then has to select one of his Pawns to use for the challenge and clicks save. Now User2 needs to either accept/decline the challenge.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how the challenges should be setup. My thought is that each Pawn will have a self-referential many-to-many relationship, almost like a friendship relationship would be setup. However, I don't know if I should consider the challenge something related to the User or the Pawn.

Whats the best way to model something like this?

**EDIT:**

Here's a diagram of what I'm trying to accomplish. I definitley think I need some sort of association setup. Result would hold statistics of that Pawn for that Challenge (something like time_spent, clicks_made, etc.). Challenge would also have a column for winner or something similar.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your challenge may have association defined for each type of pawn.

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes :challengee_id, :challenger_id

  belongs_to :challengee, class_name: "Pawn"
  belongs_to :challenger, class_name: "Pawn"

  has_many :results
end
```

Pawns will have associations for each type of challenge.

```
class Pawn < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes :user_id

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :results
  has_many :initiated_challenges, class_name: "Challenge", foreign_key: :challenger_id
  has_many :received_challenges, class_name: "Challenge", foreign_key: :challengee_id
end
```

It's probably ok to denormalize challenge_id for the result records.

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes: pawn_id, challenge_id, :result
  belongs_to :pawn
  belongs_to :challenge
end
```

Your user can have associations to pawns and to challenges through pawns. A simple way to get both challenge types associated with a user would be to combine the results of the two challenge associations (initiated and received) into one method #challenge.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pawns
  has_many :initiated_challenges, through: :pawns, source: :initiated_challenges
  has_many :received_challenges, through: :pawns, source: :received_challenges

  def challenges
    initiated_challenges + received_challenges
  end
end
```

Performance optimizations for this method could include denormalizing the user_ids on to Challenge as :challengee_user_id and :challenger_user_id... or caching a list of challenge ids on the user so you make one query instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up another table called `Challenges` with fields `challenger_id, challengee_id, status`. The challenger and challengee ids would represent the pawns of course, not the user. The status would represent `challenge_pending, challenge_on_going`, there are other ways to do this obviously, but this one one.

This has the added benefit of allowing you to restrict pawn-to-pawn challenges to one each very easily if that's your desired behavior, among other things.

In your view controller

```
@challenges = Challenge.where("challengee_id IN (?)", Pawn.find_all_by_owner_id(current_user.id).map{|u| u[:id]})
@challenged = Challenge.where("challenger_id IN (?)", Pawn.find_all_by_owner_id(current_user.id).map{|u| u[:id]})
```

In your view

```
<%= @challenges.each do |challenge| %>
  whatever
<% end %>
```

Comment: Lets say I also wanted to list a Users challenges on his profile page, how would I be able to find them and list then efficiently?

Comment: `Challenge.find_all_by_challengee_id(current_user.id)` will give you the list of all challenges where your user is the challengee

Comment: But isn't the Challenger and Challengee ids for the Pawns?

Comment: You're right, sorry. `Challenge.where("challengee_id IN (?)", Pawn.find_all_by_owner_id(current_user.id).map{|u| u[:id]})`

Comment: This would list all challenges that the user has had initiated towards him. I want to list all challenges he has initiated as well as the ones others have initiated with him. How would I be able to get all these as one array?

Comment: You'll need a separate query, but it's basically the same: `Challenge.where("challenger_id IN (?)", Pawn.find_all_by_owner_id(current_user.id).map{|u| u[:id]})`

Answer (score 1):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pawns
end

class Pawn < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :challengers, class_name: 'Challenge'
    has_many :challengees, class_name: 'Challenge'

    belongs_to :result
end

class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :challenger, class_name: 'Pawn'
    belongs_to :challengee, class_name: 'Pawn'

    belongs_to :result
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :challenge
    has_one :winner, class_name: 'Pawn'
end
```